# What is the meaning of "You are only coming through in waves"

Tags: meaning

What are all the possible meanings of "You are only coming through in waves"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of song lyrics.

Comment: ...whereas I give a +1, because its an awesome song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're referring to the song lyric in Pink Floyd's *Comfortably Numb*. In this context, the singer has been given some very strong drugs and is fading in and out of coherency. Following up on @stib's answer, the "waves" here refers to the "ebb and flow" of consciousness and awareness. So the conversation that he is a part of is only filtering into his mind in bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

"Waves" implies a an ebb and flow, like the motion of waves on a shore.

When talking about people coming through in waves you could be talking of a mass of people, for example a crowd or army, moving so that there was a surge of people "coming through", followed by a respite, followed by another surge and so on.

"Coming through" could also mean communicating, as on a two-way radio. "Coming through in waves" in this case could mean that the reception was fading in and out, so there would be a period where the person could be heard, followed by static, and so on.